# search templates of draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

How can I search for templates, resources, examples of draw.io diagrams?

Looks like draw.io does not has a repository for this. Also online resources are scarce.

Comment: Something like https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-libs ?